# Why is GetRequestToken not working?

Tags: c#, twitter, mono, tweetsharp

I have the following little snippet that won't compile:

```
using TweetSharp.Twitter.Fluent;

//...

var twitter = FluentTwitter.CreateRequest();
twitter.Authentication.GetRequestToken("...", "...");
```

...and it gives me the following error:

```
Main.cs(12,12): Error CS1061: Type `TweetSharp.Twitter.Fluent.
IFluentTwitterAuthentication' does not contain a definition for `GetRequestToken'
and no extension method `GetRequestToken' of type TweetSharp.Twitter.Fluent.
IFluentTwitterAuthentication' could be found (are you missing a using directive
or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (StackBot)
```

Which is strange because according to [TweetSharp's website](http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=OAuthWorkflow), that's supposed to be valid code.

Am I forgetting something or is there some other assembly I need to reference?

I'm using Mono 2.4 on Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit.

---

I may have found a clue here. Using the assembly browser, I have discovered that `IFluentTwitterAuthentication` has the following definition:

```
public abstract interface IFluentTwitterAuthentication : IFluentAuthentication
{
    // Properties
    public abstract IFluentTwitter Root { get; }
}
```

...which leads me to believe that something is not quite right with the assembly.

Comment: I`m having tons of problems with all versions of this library... I`m simple unable to get the tokens.

Comment: Ya, me too. I eventually just switched to DotNetOpenAuth and managed the interaction with Twitter myself.

Answer (score 1):

Their code seems to be:

```
var twitter = FluentTwitter.CreateRequest ()
    .Authentication.GetRequestToken("...", "...");
```

which is quite different than yours:

```
var twitter = FluentTwitter.CreateRequest();
twitter.Authentication.GetRequestToken("...", "...");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your USING statements may be missing...Try this:

```
using TweetSharp.Twitter.Fluent;
using TweetSharp.Twitter.Model;
using TweetSharp.Twitter.Extensions;


//...

var twitter = FluentTwitter.CreateRequest();
twitter.Authentication.GetRequestToken("...", "...");
```